TypeScript unionizes generic type param instead of intersecting it
I am trying to create a generic function that takes in a "name" and "config" as its parameters and calls a method of an object depending on these parameters. See the following code:
type Creator<Config extends Record<string, unknown>> = (config: Config) => void;

const A: Creator<{ testA: string }> = (config) => {
  console.log(config.testA);
};

const B: Creator<{ testB: string }> = (config) => {
  console.log(config.testB);
};

const collection = { A, B };

function call<T extends keyof typeof collection>(
  name: T,
  config: Parameters<(typeof collection)[T]>[0]
) {
  const create = collection[name];

  create(config);
  // TypeScript complains here about "config", with this error:
  // Property 'testB' is missing in type '{ testA: string; }' but required in type '{ testB: string; }'.
}

Is there something one can do about this behavior? The code would be totally valid (in my opinion).

This is effectively ms/TS#30581 and the solution is a particular sort of generic indexing code as described in ms/TS#47109. See this playground link and the linked q/a above for more information.
